# Go - Convert raw byte string into uuid

Tags: string, go, escaping, byte

I am trying to convert raw byte strings into UUIDs in my program as follows:

Case1:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    s := `"\220\254\0021\265\235O~\244\326\216\"\227c\245\002"`
    s2, err := strconv.Unquote(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    by := []byte(s2)
    u, err := uuid.FromBytes(by)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u.String())
}
```

output:

```
90ac0231-b59d-4f7e-a4d6-8e229763a502
```

Case2:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    s := `"\235\273\'\021\003\261@\022\226\275o\265\322\002\211\263"`
    s2, err := strconv.Unquote(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    by := []byte(s2)
    u, err := uuid.FromBytes(by)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u.String())
}
```

output:

```
panic: invalid syntax

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox1756881518/prog.go:14 +0x149

Program exited.
```

The above program is working with string `"\220\254\0021\265\235O~\244\326\216\"\227c\245\002"` but fails at converting string `"\235\273\'\021\003\261@\022\226\275o\265\322\002\211\263"` into uuid. How can I convert these strings into UUIDs?

Comment: What is the syntax used by the strings?   The strconv.Unquote function removes quotes using Go string literal syntax.  The text `\'` is not valid in a Go string literal (it's valid in rune literals, not string literals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If fails because of `\'`. When using backticks, all backslashes are literally backslashes and not escape sequences, so you are passing raw backslash `\`, followed by single quote `'` to the `strconv.Unquote`. It causes invalid syntax. There are two workarounds here:

### First

Just replace this line:

```
s := `"\235\273\'\021\003\261@\022\226\275o\265\322\002\211\263"`
```

with this:

```
s := `"\235\273'\021\003\261@\022\226\275o\265\322\002\211\263"`
```

So there is `'` not `\'`. But if you need to programmatically convert the string, use the second approach.

### Second

Import `"strings"`:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)
```

And replace `\'` with `'`:

```
s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, `\'`, `'`)
```

So the full code looks like this now:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    s := `"\235\273\'\021\003\261@\022\226\275o\265\322\002\211\263"`
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, `\'`, `'`)
    s2, err := strconv.Unquote(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    by := []byte(s2)
    u, err := uuid.FromBytes(by)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u.String())
}
```